# ¿Cómo hacer un setImageResource de un ImageView con Glide?

Tags: android

Estoy intentando por todos los medios posibles el implementar el `setter` `imageView.setImageResource` de `ImageView` cogiendo como parametro una imagen url en `String` que la obtengo con el framework `Glide`, pero no funciona.

Tampoco funciona el hacer `Glide.with(contexto).load(urlString).into(imageView)` ya que me añade la imagen muy grande y no puedo hacer resize...

**DESDE RESOURCE LOCAL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**DESDE GLIDE**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien uso este metodo para crear Parallax y veo que solo me funciona bien con el setImageResource...

```
public void parallax(final View v) {

        final Rect r = new Rect();
        v.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

        if (aux != r.top) {
            aux = r.top;
            v.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    v.setY((float) (r.top / 1.0));
                }
            });//2.0
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Glide siempre hace resize de las imágenes adaptándose al tamaño del imageview. de todas formas puede redimensionar la imagen usando el método `.override(300, 200)`

Comment: Muy importante lo que comenta ClarkXP, no entiendo que es lo que no funciona, no carga la imagen?, no hace resize? explica un ´poco más.

Comment: Creo que en tu ImageView estás usando WRAP_CONTENT en height, prueba con darle una medida fija, y usa centerCrop para que la imagen cubra bien el imageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se realiza `imageView.setImageResource()` lo que se realiza en `Glide` es pasar la referencia del `ImageView` para que cargue en ella la imagen.

Para cargar una imagen debes asegurar la url contiene una ruta de imagen:

```
Glide.with(this)
       .load(urlString)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(imageView);
```

para realizar un resize por ejemplo de `200x200` px:

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(urlString)
     .override(200, 200)
     .into(imageView);
```

#### Para cargar imágenes desde recursos:

a) desde imagen en recursos necesitamos el id:

```
Glide.with(this)
 .load(R.id.resource_id)
```

b) desde `assets`:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/nombre_imagen"))
```

Comment: No si eso lo sabia, el problema era la diferencia entre hacerlo con glide o desde un local.... Actualizo ahora mismo la pregunta! Gracias por el interes!

Comment: He visto las imágenes en tu pregunta,usa la propiedad CenterCrop() en Glide y dime como se muestra.

Comment: Igual que si no lo pongo... :(

Comment: Sería de ayuda ver tu layout o el código del ImageView, veo que mencionas tambien usas un  parallax, usas el coordinatorLayout?

Comment: No... solo uso ese metodo de parallax... ya que no uso appbar en la aplicacion y no puedo usar bien el parallax con coordinator layout

Comment: De la manera que uso el parallax es la siguiente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO82ES_RiSQ gracias por tu interes!